# Does the Piper Aztec have flaps and slats and if so what kind?

Tags: aerodynamics, commercial-aviation, flaps, slats

I was just wondering if any one knows if the piper Aztec has flaps and what kind. Also if the piper Aztec has any other high lift devices.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Piper Aztec has standard (plain) flaps:

[image]
Source: [Sky4Buy.com](http://sky4buy.com/1964-PIPER-PA-23-250-AZTEC-AIRFRAME-NICE-INTERIOR-GEAR-UP-DAMAGE-CHEAP-381236610083/01918)

Another View:

[image]
Source: Same as above

The Aztec does not have slats as can be seen in the image from the front of the wing:

[image]
Source: [NWAviators.com](http://www.nwaviators.com/aztec/aztec_pics.asp)

Here is a close-up view of the wing of the plane in the first two images (damaged, but no slats):

[image]
Source: [Sky4Buy.com](http://sky4buy.com/1964-PIPER-PA-23-250-AZTEC-AIRFRAME-NICE-INTERIOR-GEAR-UP-DAMAGE-CHEAP-381236610083/01918)

Other than the flaps (and wings) there are no other high-lift devices installed on a Piper Aztec.